# Connect to torrent "swarm" or DHT with ruby

Tags: ruby, p2p, bittorrent, dht

I'm probably lacking in some fundamental understanding of how BitTorrent, DHT, and the "swarm" work, as I'm not even sure if DHT and the "swarm" are one and the same.

However, I'm trying to find peers, the number of peers, and some statistics about a torrent from its magnet link (and hash).

I've looked for some libraries to accomplish this, but they seem either outdated or unrelated, or just bencode things.

How do I go about connecting and requesting information? A brief explanation would be delightful.

Answer (score 4):

official specs: http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html
non-official spec: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification

*BEncoding* is a data serialization format used in bittorrent for several purposes

The DHT is a global, decentralized, iterative, UDP-based lookup system which can be used to locate clients participating in a particular *swarm* based on an *infohash*, which can be either obtained directly from a *magnet link* or calculated from a *.torrent* metadata file.

If you have the announce URL for a *tracker* (an optional part of the torrent file or the magnet link) you can obtain client addresses directly from a tracker.

Once you have obtained client addresses for a particular swarm you can connect to them - or they will connect to you if you have announced yourself to the DHT/a responsible tracker - using the bittorrent wire protocol, which is basically an asynchronous, binary messaging protocol.

To get a fully-functioning, state-of-the-art bittorrent client you have to implement the following:

- a DHT node (bencoding over UDP)
- tracker announce and scrape protocol (uses bencoding over HTTP and a custom binary prtocol over UDP)
- the bittorrent wire protocol (custom binary protocol over TCP with an optional extension layer. some of the messages are bencoded. A congestion-avoiding UDP-based transport protocol called µTP also exists as alternative to TCP)
- a torrent file parser (bencoding, obviously)
- general stuff like queueing active torrents, file management, highly concurrent network IO

This is a lot of work which to my knowledge has not been done in ruby. So either you have a lot ahead of yourself or you might want to use a bittorrent library written in a different language (e.g. libtorrent) or interface with a client providing a web service (e.g. transmission).

Comment: Okay thank you for this explanation. Say I have a magnet link with just the hash and torrent name - what then?

Comment: then you need to locate clients through the DHT, connect to them and use the metadata exchange extension to get the metadata file. then you can start downloading the data proper.
There also are some torrent archives which serve the torrent files based on their hashes.

Comment: How do I go about "locating" these clients?

Comment: If you want to do it manually you can just google for the hash, download the torrent and start it in a bittorrent client. To do it programmatically you need a DHT implementation.

Comment: Okay this is still very fuzzy. How would I implement DHT? It'd be great if you were more specific because I plan on writing a ruby gem

Comment: By reading the specs (which i have already linked), [the kademlia paper](http://infinite-source.de/az/whitepapers/kademlia_optimized.pdf) and the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) and looking at existing implementations.